# Parse iOS API - add channels

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform, channel

I have configured my Parse reception api like so:

```
[Parse setApplicationId:@"***" clientKey:@"***"];

[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|
 UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

and

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
     PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}
```

Then in my code, I add channels to subscribe to like so:

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

for (Room *aRoom in rooms) {

    NSString *strChannel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pr_%@", aRoom.roomId];
    [array addObject:strChannel];
}

[currentInstallation setChannels:array];
```

In my example, the channel is "pr_4".

When I push something on this channel though, the parse dashboard tells me that nobody has subscribed to the channel "pr_4". I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you go to your dashboard, in the "Installations" class, and check if the channel is set for your test user ?

Comment: I believe you forgot to call *[currentInstallation saveInBackground];* after you set the channels array. Can you add that line and try again ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the code you provided, you never actually save the `PFInstallation` object to parse.com. You should add :

```
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

at the end of your code, right after you set the channels.

---

Side-note: you can also use the method `subscribeToChannelInBackground:` from the `PFPush` class in order to subscribe a device to a channel:

> ### `subscribeToChannelInBackground:`
>
> Asynchronously subscribes the device to a channel of push notifications.
>
> `+ (void)subscribeToChannelInBackground:(NSString *)channel`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> channel
>
> The channel to subscribe to. The channel name must start with
>   a letter and contain only letters, numbers, dashes, and underscores.

Comment: Yes that did it… Thank you very much! I will look into the subscribeToChannelInBackground method too, because I think I will need to use it in another part of my app. Thanks again!

Comment: Can we subscribe a ParseUser to a channel too ?

Comment: @alexsummers : Nope ! As they say in the [push guide](https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#installations/iOS), "*The **Installation** object is where you store all the data needed to target push notifications.*" In fact, if you think about it, you shouldn't handle notifications based on a user but based on a device, as a single user can have multiple devices with different notifications settings. This is why you need to use *currentInstallation* which is "linked" to a device.

Comment: I agree. But in case,I have a SignIn system, where users can log in/out. Whats the best way to handle it? One hack I figured was to assign a user channels, and copy it to an installation when he signs in, and remove them when the user signs out.

Comment: Because what I need is when a User performs an action, his/her friends need to be notified. So I subscribe a user to his friends channels.

Comment: @alexsummers : Sorry, but I haven't played with the PFUsers class that much yet.. Maybe you'll have better luck opening a new question and/or ask directly on their forum ?

Comment: Yup. I think they've stopped responding on their forum much. Will do one here. Thanks :)